# WP7 (windows phone 7) How to zoom with the PhotoCamera?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, camera

I'm using the `PhotoCamera` for an AR app and I was thinking that a zoom in/out function would be a nice one. 
But I can't figure out how to do it. There is no zoom method in the `PhotoCamera` Class.

Does anyone have a lead on how to do it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730867/how-to-programmatically-zoom-in-the-feed-from-the-camera A solution is also provided there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've trying to figure out the same problem. It seems, that there is no way to do any zooming with PhotoCamera class. 
The only way to implement a zoom is digitally zooming by cropping the image and scaling it. One way to do this, is simply to scale the UI element (for example Rectangle) that the videobrush is set to. If you are processing the frames, you have to apply the same cropping and scaling to the preview buffer that you get from the camera class.