# How to programmatically zoom-in the feed from the camera?

Tags: windows-phone-7, camera, zooming

I want to be able to programmatically adjust the zoom level of the camera feed.

I do not know whether cell-phone cameras have optical zoom or not and if Windows phone 7 lets a programmer control it (if it is there). If it does, please let me know how.

If it doesn't, I want to able to digitally magnify the camera feed (digital zoom). A pointer to how to do this programmatically would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Phone 7 hardware specification does not include optical zoom. You can access the live images from the camera in Silverlight code via a CaptureSource as described in this [MSDN tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394041%28VS.92%29.aspx). You can capture images via [AsyncCaptureImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.capturesource.captureimageasync%28VS.95%29.aspx), which provides you with a [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28VS.95%29.aspx) which you can then use to zoom digitally.